# django display textfields

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

I have a form with `textfield`s in Django, and users enter texts line by line.
When I look at the entries in admin side, I saw exactly how user wrote it but when I display it on my website, in Django templates, it just joins the sentences and I couldn't display the text line by line anymore.

To illustrate, user enters text as

-bla

-bla1

-bla2

However, it looks like in my page as

-bla1-bla2-bla3

This is my code in the template:

```
<div>
   <p>
      {{ rev.myTextField }}
   </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In HTML, newlines between text don't imply a newline in display; you need to use HTML to insert the newline. The most straightforward way is with the `<br />` tag, although there are other methods as well.

Django has a template filter for this: use `|linebreaks`. [Here's the Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/templates/builtins/#linebreaks).

So, change:

```
{{ rev.myTextField }}
```

to:

```
{{ rev.myTextField|linebreaks }}
```

Comment: thanks that's great.But what if I would like to display only 200 charactes after line breaks.. Is there any way to do this ?

Comment: There's a built-in `truncatewords` filter, but not a truncate characters filter. You'll need to add a custom filter: Here's the code: http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1471/

Answer (score 1):

Try "safe" [tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/templates/builtins/#safe)

```
{{ rev.myTextField|safe }}
```

Answer (score 0):

using

> {{ rev.myTextField|linebreaks }}

disables `<small>` tag, its better to use

> {{ rev.myTextField|linebreaksbr }}

it just put `<br>` tag, not `<p>`