# In Django what is the method of a `TextField` / `Field` object that returns its content?

Tags: django

In Django when needing to display the content of an object of type  `django.db.models.fields.TextField` in a template, if this object is denoted as `textfield`, we can display it with the simple `{{ textfield }}` command.

However, while exploring the code of `django.db.models.fields.TextField`, I did not find any method returning the *content* of the `TextField`. Indeed, while checking `django.db.models.fields.TextField` and its super class `django.db.models.fields.Field` I did not find any method that do the job.

Thus, is there such a method returning the content of a `TextField` or even a `Field`, else what is the machinery used here to return it ?

Comment: You just reference the field by variable name?

Answer (score 0):

That's not how Django fields work. Fields are attributes of the class, not the instance, and are used for loading and saving values from the database; the attribute on the instance is just the plain value.

Comment: I talk about the `TextField` object. Maybe I have misunderstood something, but TextField is really an object that instanciates a class and not just an attribute. The class: `django.db.models.fields.TextField`. Example of use: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8204465/django-display-textfields

Comment: Yes, but it is not the value that is stored on the instance itself. You can check: `type(my_instance.textfield)` is `str`, not `TextField`.

Comment: Ok, I think I have understood. When fields are used directly from the class, that is as class attribute, they are used as `Field` objects, but when the same class owning this `Field` attributes is instanciated, then this attributes are set to strings ? Is that it?